# show all users from table by pagination

Tags: php, pagination

i got large amount of users into my table and i want to made an small script to show all users as 10 per page

I'm using this script http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html but its showing only 1 result per page.
As they are saying on pic 7 i loop the code to show the users as this :

```
    $id = $row["id"];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $date = $row['date'];
```

And its echo-ed as this:

```
    <?php

    echo '<div class="content">
    <h1><a href="edit.php?user=' . $id . '"> ' . $username . ' </a></h1>
    <div class="content_item">
    <p>'.$date.'</p>
    </div>
    </div>';

?>
```

However i dont understand why its showing only 1 result per page!
I setted $start as 0 and $limit as 10

Answer (score 1):

You have to place this echo code in a Loop, which would echo the Details of Users repeatedly.

For Example-

```
foreach($results as $r)
{
    echo $r->id;
    echo $r->username;
}
```